# Concordância do infinitivo

Tags: concordância-verbal, infinitivo-pessoal

*"Creio ter o médico e a família ido clinicar em São Paulo"*.

Na frase acima, considerando que o sujeito composto, por estar no meio da locução, não está posposto, o infinitivo *"ter"* não deveria ter sido empregado na 3º pessoa do plural (*"terem"*)?

Comment: A frase está mal feita, mal escrita. clinicar quer dizer: Ser médico de profissão.

"clinicar", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2024, https://dicionario.priberam.org/clinicar. Um mêdico pode clinicar. Uma família, não.

Comment: Obrigado! Vi essa frase em uma questão da FGV e fiquei na dúvida.

Comment: Na verdade, o que a pessoa queria dizer poderia ser várias coisas, inclusive  ter um médico em São Paulo e ir a São Paulo com a família  para receber um tratamento, né?

Comment: É possível a família clinicar se for uma família de médicos. Talvez o texto esteja também fazendo uso de alguma figura de linguagem. Embora a definição apresentada pela amiga esteja correta, não é o suficiente para dizer que a frase está mal escrita.

Comment: Relendo sua pergunta, acabei de notar que você diz que o sujeito não está posposto. Por que você diria isso?

Comment: Achei que não fosse possível considerá-lo posposto, por ele estar no meio da locução. De qualquer modo, a FGV considerou correto não ser possível empregar a forma "terem" (acredito que a justificativa seja semântica mesmo, pois apenas o médico pode clinicar)

Comment: A locução é o sujeito composto, e que está posposto, então (de acordo com as fontes na minha resposta), o verbo poderia tanto estar no plural quanto no singular. Quanto à semântica, não posso dizer nada mesmo.

Comment: A frase precisa ser re-escrita.  Mas fui lá pegar o exercío que diz:  Assinale **a frase** em que o infinitivo admite dupla concordância. E acho que não é a que foi postada porque soa muito feia.//Exato, Alexsander, só um médico pode clinicar. Resultado? Eles também usam frases mal feitas para pegarem (Rs) os alunos desatentos/distraídos?

Answer (score -1):

Bem observado, mas quando o verbo vem antes do sujeito, este tem a possibilidade de concordar com o sujeito mais próximo.

Fontes:
1: [https://www.soportugues.com.br/(...)/sint53.php](https://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/sint/sint53.php)
2: [https://brasilescola.uol.com.br/(...)sujeito-composto.htm](https://brasilescola.uol.com.br/amp/gramatica/concordancia-verbal-os-casos-especiais-sujeito-composto.htm)

Comment: A frase não tem nenhum sentido do jeito que está escrita.

Comment: @Lambie Negativou minha resposta só por ser minha, como sempre? Chegou a ler dentro das fontes que apresentei? Levou em consideração que, talvez, a frase tenha sido apresentada dentro de um contexto, omitida pelo autor da pergunta? Ademais, *não vejo incorreção gramatical alguma na frase*, mas caso possa objetivamente apontar algum erro, poderemos conversar a respeito.

Comment: (Eu) creio ter x. O verbo não vem antes do sujeito.  O sujeito (oculto, digamos) é o pronome eu. Coloquei voto negativo porque a redação da frase sofre de uma redação incorreta.  A frase vem de uma concurso público da Câmara de deputados.